# How can I plot a simple plot with seaborn from a python dictionary?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {'Southampton': '33.7%', 'Cherbourg': '55.36%', 'Queenstown': '38.96%'}
```

How can I have a simple plot with 3 bars showing the values of each key in a dictionary?

I've tried:

```
sns.barplot(x=my_dict.keys(), y = int(my_dict.values()))
```

But I get :

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict_values'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You are trying to convert each value (eg "xx.xx%") into a number. `my_dict.values()` returns all values as a `dict_values` object. `int(my_dict.values()))` means converting the set of all values to a single integer, not converting each of the values to an integer. The former, naturally, makes no sense.
2. Python can't interpret something like "12.34%" as an integer or a float. You need to remove the percentage sign, ie `float("12.34%"[:-1])`.
3. <s>Dictionaries are not ordered. Therefore, `my_dict.keys()` and `my_dict.values()` are not guaranteed to return keys and values in the key-value pairs in the same order, for example, the keys you get may be `['Southampton', 'Cherbourg', 'Queenstown']` and the values you get may be `"55.36%", "33.7", "38.96%"`.</s> This is no longer a problem in Python >= 3.7 and CPython 3.6; see @AmphotericLewisAcid's comment below.

With all these issues fixed:

```
keys = list(my_dict.keys())
# get values in the same order as keys, and parse percentage values
vals = [float(my_dict[k][:-1]) for k in keys]
sns.barplot(x=keys, y=vals)
```

You get:
[image]

Comment: Regarding point 3, dictionaries are now ordered as of Python 3.7 - https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html. `my_dict.keys()` and `my_dict.values()` are guaranteed to return the same order. This was also unofficially implemented in C-python 3.6 (not sure about Iron Python or PyPy)

Comment: @AmphotericLewisAcid learned that a few months ago after I wrote this answer - thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the values to numeric, right now they are strings:

```
import seaborn as sns
my_dict = {'Southampton': '33.7%', 'Cherbourg': '55.36%', 'Queenstown': '38.96%'}
perc =  [float(i[:-1]) for i in my_dict.values()]
sns.barplot(x=list(my_dict.keys()),y=perc)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, can you check my answer if that would be a viable solution as well?

Answer (score 2):

I did the following:

I first removed the `%` sign from the dict.

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.items())
ax = sns.barplot(x=0, y=1, data=my_df)
ax.set(xlabel = 'Cities', ylabel='%', title='Title')
```

[image]

[image]